# How to alter a vm snapshot's ip and mac address?

Tags: vmware-vmdk

I have installed VMware and taken a snapshot of a VM.
I want to change the virtual operating system's ip address and mac address in the snapshot state.

Is there a way to accomplish this by editing the VM's files?
I don't know whether this way is feasible. If you know how to implement this, please tell me.

Thank you very much! Best wishs!

Comment: VMware is a company, not a product. Please edit you question (and its tags) to clarify what product and version you are running.

Comment: Yes,I am sorry,I didn't say clearly,I have installed VMware' product.Here is a software configuration.
Product: VMware WorkStation
Version:7.0.0build-203739
Please continue to provide advice, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The feature you are asking for is called "[snapshots in a process tree](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_preserve_sshot_tree.html)" in VMWare terms and "snapshot branching" everywhere else and is a feature of the VMWare Workstation product line:

[image: snapshots in a process tree]

Note that vSphere / ESX(i) products do not have this feature. Technically, [there is support for linked clones](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/linked_vms_note.pdf) in vCenter for use with the VMWare View VDI solution. Unfortunately, the vSphere/vCenter client does not expose any controls to manage linked clones, so you would need to revert to API calls to use it. Of course, there are scripts readily available making life easier when you need to use this feature - [vGhettoLinkedClone](https://s3.amazonaws.com/virtuallyghetto-download/vGhettoLinkedClone.html) being one of them. But mind that this use case would not be supported by VMWare.

Comment: Yes,I am sorry,I did mention the problem,I didn't say clearly,I have installed VMware' product.Here is a software configuration.
Product: VMware WorkStation
Version:7.0.0build-203739
Please continue to provide advice, thank you!

Comment: @user164697 what would be your question? Have you read the respective documentation? Did you see the option to [clone virtual machines off snapshots](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_preserve_sshot_clone.html)? There really is not much more to tell you than what has already been told at the current stage.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You cannot go backwards and change the state of a snapshot (at least in ESX(i)) You can take a snapshot, change it in the current state, and then revert and your changes go away.

The fact that you're asking about this makes me fear that you're trying to use snapshots for something that they're not well-suited to do.

/edit - syneticon-dj points out that there is support for this in VDI and Workstation. I didn't realize that, so my answer only applies to ESX and ESXi.

Comment: Sorry Matt, but as a fact statement it is inaccurate.

Comment: Yes,I am sorry,I did mention the problem,I didn't say clearly,I have installed VMware' product.Here is a software configuration.
Product: VMware WorkStation
Version:7.0.0build-203739
Please continue to provide advice, thank you!